# How to have 2 programs running at the same time without toggling between them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, c#, forms

I am currently creating a program that needs to allow its functions to work when Microsoft Office programs are open.  This program works only if I were to toggle from them with Alt and Tab.

With using C# code, how could I make my program and Microsoft Office programs (ie: Word, Excel, Power Point, Outlook) be highlighted at the same time as if I can make changes to both programs at the same time?

I would like to have both a Microsoft Office program active as if you clicked on it with the mouse and have my program active as if you clicked on it with the mouse, but keeping both programs active and not toggling between them.

Would I have to create a function to make my mouse click on my program and a Microsoft Office program at the same time?

Comment: You are confusing *"running at the same time"* with the concept of the active window.  Having more than one active window at a time will lead to confusion.  However see [Selecting two windows at the same time on Windows 7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/selecting-two-windows-at-the-same-time-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Windows. What you're talking about is known as the system **[focus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28computing%29?wprov=sfla1)**. It defines which application is active and will receive user input.

Windows is not designed to allow multiple applications to receive user input simultaneously. This would cause considerable confusion to end users if it were possible. For example, by pressing the delete key a user intending to delete an unwanted character in one application could inadvertently delete a file in another.

It will be necessary to modify the behavior of your target application to produce the results you want without this requirement.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you add a plugin for Windows Forms in Visual Studios to talk to another program? language c#

Comment: I don't know. They would be a good question for Stack Overflow.